# Number format of an HTML POST

Tags: php, html

I have an `HTML` form that use `POST` to send data to a php file. The form is created dynamically and has a number of check boxes that can change. There is a hidden piece of data sent which is the number of persons in the list - *numberOfPersons*.

[image]

The *echo $personCount;* line shows that the *numberOfPersons* is received but I am unsure that the format is correct because will only ever show the first checked name in the list that was posted.

Could it be that the receiving php file does not know that *numberOfPersons* is a number? Do I need to set the format to integer somehow? Or is there another error?

The file that receives the post looks like this:

```
$personCount=$_POST["numberOfPersons"];

echo $personCount;

for ($intLoop = 1; $intLoop <= $personCount; $intLoop++)
{
echo $intLoop;
echo"<br>";
}
```

Comment: `for ($intLoop = 1; $intLoop <= intval($personCount); $intLoop++)` it's most likely a string if the value came from a form.

Comment: there is probably another error because `$personCount` will casted to integer automatically

Comment: _“because will only ever show the first checked name in the list that was posted”_ – there is nothing in your code that outputs these values.

Comment: use count($personCount) and process the loop

Comment: Change this "$personCount=$_POST["numberOfPersons"]);" to "$personCount = $_POST["numberOfPersons"];"

Comment: @RenatoLeite - yes typo on question - edited now

Comment: @CBroe - I removed from here to make it clearer to read. How wrong I was. Thanks

Comment: @Sundar this does not work because there is only 1 personCount. It is the value of personCount I need. But thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you set the name of the form element as an array...

```
name="numberOfPersons[]"
```

for each of the check boxes then you can query the result posted using either var_dump or print_r to see what the post is producing.